# Некоректный вывод индекса функцией find()

Tags: c++, find

Не понимаю, почему такое странное поведение у функции `find()`.

В результате из примера ниже, в консоли печатается не `5`, а `10`. Почему так происходит?

```
string b = "Издательский бизнес сегодня немыслим без компьютерных издательских систем,";

auto a = b.find("е");
cout << a << endl;
```

Comment: Уверен - исходник в кодировке UTF-8? :)

Comment: @Harry Думаю да, а есть разница?

Comment: Конечно - при этом русские символы в длину более 1 `char`...

Comment: @Harry А простым делением на `2` решит проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашей реализации строка, состоящая из русской буквы, скорее всего, занимает 2 `char`, поэтому позиции умножаются на 2. Простое деление на 2 непереносимо, но может работать в вашем случае.

http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: Не будет работать, потому что в UTF-8 те же пробелы и запятые - по 1 байту, так что если он будет искать `б` или `ы`, то промахнется. Да и вообще, такой вывод по итератору просто не будет работать верно при делении на 2 (впрочем, как и без деления, скорее всего).